# CSV to php, file() creates extra dubbel quote on new line,

Tags: php, string, csv

Just building an easy guest book with HTML form and PHP.
I save the name, message, and time in an array. And then to a CSV-file.

When I read the CSV-file, the problem starts.
Problem is that the file() function ads extra quotes in the beginning and end. The last quote comes on a new line. These quotes are only visible in a var_dump().
What happens is that this creates a blank line.

the function:

```
// READ CSV FILE
public function readcsv($filename) {
    $rows = array();
    $fh = fopen($filename, "r");
    foreach (file($fh, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) {
        //$newline = str_replace('""', "", $line);
        //$newline = trim(html_entity_decode($newline),'"');
        $newline = preg_match('/^[a-öA-Ö0-9]{2,12}$/', $line);
        $rows[] = str_getcsv($newline);
    }

    return $rows;
    //close the file
    fclose($fh);
}
```

I have tried str_replace(), trim(html_entity_decode() ande preg_match.
I just can´t get it to work. The outcome still is as follow:
**print_r() =**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Peter,"test message one","2020-07-04: 14.40"

    [1] => Bjorn,"test number 2","2020-07-04: 14.40"

    [2] => Nina,"Test number 3","2020-07-04: 14.40"
)
```

and
**var_dump() =**

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(45) "Peter,"test message one","2020-07-04: 14.40"
"
  [1]=>
  string(42) "Bjorn,"test number 2","2020-07-04: 14.40"
"
  [2]=>
  string(41) "Nina,"Test number 3","2020-07-04: 14.40"
"}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: you would usually just use `file( $filename )` rather than opening a file handle with `fopen`... but why this approach? The CSV file is not very resilient - why not a database?

Comment: When print_r shows information, it does not quote strings, however var_dump does. Here is a sample of what you are seeing: https://3v4l.org/KIeI2. So the quotes do not exist, that is an artifact of debugging, however your data does include a new line character.

Comment: From the PHP manual: `"preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred"`

Comment: With your function I get `"file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given"` and as a result `"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius well I droped the fopen, dont now why I put it in...
It´s just for learning purpose I using CSV.

@c

Comment: and what is the problem? You want to parse each line and create an array from the data on each line or are you concerned with extra quotes from somewhere? The `preg_match` also doesn't do anything sensible here as far as I can see...

Comment: @ChrisHaas aha thanks, well It´s very strange now becuse I try get rid of the  \n with str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $line);    and it now it´s working. BUT strange becuse the same code from a method declered in a class don´t work. But if i put exactly the same code in normal function it works. 

also, I has problem get new method to work in my class.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Well just wanted get rid of the extra lines, otherwise I cant make it a Multidimensional Array

Comment: what `extra lines` are these?

Comment: the ones created by /n as chrisHaas pointed out

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very simple CSV source file consisting of just 3 lines ( as per your question ) - for the benefit of the following PHP I named it `gb.csv` and stored in the same directory as the test script.

```
Peter,"This is a test message","2020-07-01: 11.20"
Rita,"This is a fantastic feature...","2020-07-04: 14.40"
Susan,"Wowser... what wonders next I wonder","2020-06-02: 14.42"
```

With a slightly modified version of your original file

```
function readcsv( $filename ) {
    $rows = array();
    $data = file( $filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
    foreach( $data as $line ) {
        $rows[] = str_getcsv( $line );
    }
    return $rows;
}


$arr=readcsv( 'gb.csv' );
printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $arr, true ) );
```

This will yield a multi-dimensional array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Peter
            [1] => This is a test message
            [2] => 2020-07-01: 11.20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rita
            [1] => This is a fantastic feature...
            [2] => 2020-07-04: 14.40
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Susan
            [1] => Wowser... what wonders next I wonder
            [2] => 2020-06-02: 14.42
        )

)
```